# Crypto Encryption

Tags: java, php, cryptography

I want to do the encryption as per requirement in php.
For the same i have to use the cryptoj.jar library of java

when i execute the command to encrypt the URL in cmd after change the directory with the help of cd command like

```
cd c://wamp/www/crypto
```

And after finish this when i execute the follwing command in cmd it execute perfectly & give me the encrypted value after press the enter... the command is below

```
 java -cp cryptoj.jar; EncryptURLParams "this is the demo parameters"
```

i want to achieve this at PHP level but i get 127 code always, this is what i am doing right now.

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/crypto/';  
$last_line = exec('java -cp '.$path.'cryptoj.jar; EncryptURLParams "source=BAClubs&identifier=123456&timestamp=2014-02-21 09:59:37.498" 2>&1', $retval);

echo $last_line;
echo $retval;
```

Any suggestion guys how to achieve that at php level, what is the mistake that i do in php code..??

i also used the exec & passthru command but same result i got.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path of the java binary?

Comment: @JesperBunnyJensen i am not getting you which java binary path you are talking about as i am non technical for java.. can you explain plz

Comment: I mean using exec('c:/path/to/java.exe -cp '.$path.'cryptoj.jar;..... (ofcourse replacing c:/path/to/ with the real path)

Comment: @JesperBunnyJensen i got my result after putting the jar and class file & php file in same directory like in  
    C://wamp//www/crypto  

but same thing if i apply in my project folder load php jar & class file in same directory i got the error class not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code and jar file on same folder and give relative path in command and try it.

Like below code.

//What we done in php
$path = 'java -cp ' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/crypto/cryptoj.jar; EncryptURLParams "source=BAClubs&identifier=123456&timestamp=2014-02-21 09:59:37.498" ';

$last_line = exec($path , $retval);
echo '

---

Last line of the output: ' . print_r($last_line).'

---

Return value: ' . print_r($retval);
exit;